# I have 4 dropdows and I want my table to be filtered using all the filters in there but my code cannot reach this feature

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 4 dropdowns and want my table to be filtered using all the filters in there but my code cannot reach this feature.
so the scenario is when the day, month, year, and time zone are set through the dropdowns, my table is filtered only with the last checked dropdown, here is my jquery code snippet, any help will be highly appreciated thank you all in advance

```html
<html>
   <head>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
   <script type = "text/javascript" >

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#daysDropdown,#monthsDropdown,#yearsDropdown,#tzDropdown').on('change', function() {
        var day = $('#daysDropdown').find('option:selected').val();
        var month = $('#monthsDropdown').find('option:selected').val();
        var year = $('#yearsDropdown').find('option:selected').val();
        var tz = $('#tzDropdown').find('option:selected').val();
        SearchData(day, month, year, tz);
    });
});

function SearchData(day, month, year, tz) {
    if (day.toUpperCase() == 'ALL' && month.toUpperCase() == 'ALL' && year.toUpperCase() == 'ALL' && tz.toUpperCase() == 'ALL') {
        $('#data-table tbody tr').show();
    } else {
        $('#data-table tbody tr:has(td)').each(function() {
            var rowday = $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text());
            var rowmonth = $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text());
            var rowyear = $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(3)').text());
            var rowtz = $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(5)').text());

            if (day != 'ALL' && month.toUpperCase() != 'ALL' && year != 'ALL' && tz.toUpperCase() != 'ALL') {
                if (rowday == day && rowmonth.toUpperCase() == month.toUpperCase() && rowyear == year && rowtz.toUpperCase() == tz.toUpperCase()) {
                    $(this).show();
                } else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            } else if ($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text() != '' || $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text() != '' || $(this).find('td:eq(3)').text() != '' || $(this).find('td:eq(5)').text() != '') {
                if (day != 'all') {
                    if (rowday == day) {
                        $(this).show();
                    } else {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                }
                if (month != 'all') {
                    if (rowmonth.toUpperCase() == month.toUpperCase()) {
                        $(this).show();
                    } else {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                }
                if (year != 'all') {
                    if (rowyear == year) {
                        $(this).show();
                    } else {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                }
                if (tz != 'all') {
                    if (rowtz.toUpperCase() == tz.toUpperCase()) {
                        $(this).show();
                    } else {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    }
}

</script>
   </head>
   <title>title</title>
   <body class="maincontainer">
<section class="container1">
  <div id="col-1">
    <br><br>
    <label>
               <h2>Filter By Month, Year and Time Zone:</h2>
            </label>
    <br><br>
    <div id="filter">
      <select id="daysDropdown" class="filter">
        <option value="">Day</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
      </select>
      <select id="monthsDropdown" class="filter">
        <option value="">Month</option>
        <option value="Sep">September</option>
        <option value="Oct">October</option>
      </select>
      <select id="yearsDropdown" class="filter">
        <option value="all">Year</option>
        <option value="2021">2021</option>
        <option value="2022">2022</option>
      </select>
      <select id="tzDropdown" class="filter">
        <option value="all">Time Zone</option>
        <option value="Berlin - GMT+2">Berlin - GMT+2</option>
        <option value="Egypt - GMT+2">Egypt - GMT+2</option>
        <option value="Riyadh - GMT+2">Riyadh - GMT+2</option>
        <option value="Istanbul - GMT+3">Istanbul - GMT+3</option>
        <option value="Dubai - GMT+4">Dubai - GMT+4</option>
        <option value="Kuwait - GMT+4">Kuwait - GMT+4</option>
        <option value="Kuala Lumpur - GMT+8">Kuala Lumpur - GMT+8</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div id="col-2">
      <br><br>
      <div class="row">
        <div id="table-wrapper">
          <div id="table-scroll">
            <br><br>
            <table id="data-table" style="text-align: center; width: 828px;" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="data-table_info">

              <thead>
                <tr role="row">
                  <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 197px;">Name</th>
                  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Date: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 49px;">Date</th>
                  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Month: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 67px;">Month</th>
                  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Year: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 45px;">Year</th>
                  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Time: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 58px;">Time</th>
                  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Time Zone: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 184px;">Time Zone</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 1</td>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>11:00:23</td>
                  <td>Riyadh - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 2</td>
                  <td>5</td>
                  <td>Sep</td>
                  <td>2021</td>
                  <td>18:45:42</td>
                  <td>Egypt - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 2</td>
                  <td>7</td>
                  <td>Sep</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>12:59:18</td>
                  <td>Egypt - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 2</td>
                  <td>30</td>
                  <td>Sep</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>16:20:37</td>
                  <td>Egypt - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 3</td>
                  <td>18</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>10:22:33</td>
                  <td>Kuala Lumpur - GMT+8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 3</td>
                  <td>18</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>11:03:42</td>
                  <td>Kuala Lumpur - GMT+8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 3</td>
                  <td>18</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>15:57:25</td>
                  <td>Kuala Lumpur - GMT+8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 3</td>
                  <td>18</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>16:15:04</td>
                  <td>Kuala Lumpur - GMT+8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 3</td>
                  <td>20</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>16:30:27</td>
                  <td>Kuala Lumpur - GMT+8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 3</td>
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>16:15:28</td>
                  <td>Kuala Lumpur - GMT+8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 3</td>
                  <td>24</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>09:16:29</td>
                  <td>Kuala Lumpur - GMT+8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 3</td>
                  <td>25</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>16:14:20</td>
                  <td>Kuala Lumpur - GMT+8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 4</td>
                  <td>6</td>
                  <td>Sep</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>09:15:55</td>
                  <td>Dubai - GMT+4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 4</td>
                  <td>6</td>
                  <td>Sep</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>12:10:23</td>
                  <td>Dubai - GMT+4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 4</td>
                  <td>8</td>
                  <td>Sep</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>12:00:23</td>
                  <td>Dubai - GMT+4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 4</td>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>Sep</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>11:25:02</td>
                  <td>Dubai - GMT+4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 4</td>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>Sep</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>11:25:03</td>
                  <td>Dubai - GMT+4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 4</td>
                  <td>14</td>
                  <td>Sep</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>09:23:27</td>
                  <td>Dubai - GMT+4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 4</td>
                  <td>28</td>
                  <td>Sep</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>15:20:49</td>
                  <td>Dubai - GMT+4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 4</td>
                  <td>9</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>10:02:22</td>
                  <td>Dubai - GMT+4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>Sep</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>11:25:02</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>28</td>
                  <td>Sep</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>15:58:06</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>4</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>09:35:22</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>4</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>09:35:22</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>4</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>09:56:44</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>6</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>09:58:08</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>7</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>10:11:26</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>10</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>10:49:11</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>10</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>10:51:19</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>10</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>11:25:56</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>10</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>11:41:22</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>10</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>11:45:58</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>10</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>11:49:19</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>10</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>11:58:00</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>10</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>12:05:57</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>10</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>12:30:15</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>10</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>13:31:27</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>10</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>15:34:47</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>10</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>15:38:58</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>10</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>16:31:21</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>17:07:32</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>19:37:26</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>12</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>08:33:09</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>12</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>15:46:07</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>12</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>16:17:56</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>13</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>08:45:45</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>14</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>08:53:30</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>14</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>15:35:58</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>17</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>08:33:39</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>17</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>15:36:56</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>18</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>10:19:50</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>18</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>14:16:23</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>18</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>14:16:37</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>18</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>15:46:10</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>18</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>16:15:13</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>20</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>16:24:49</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>24</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>16:53:02</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>24</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>16:53:03</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                  <td>24</td>
                  <td>Oct</td>
                  <td>2022</td>
                  <td>16:53:09</td>
                  <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <br><br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably need to `.show()` everything before filtering and while filtering just use `.hide()`. Else you disregard previous filters.

Comment: I have updated the code, can you please take a look? thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working solution. Please check this. just need to update the searchData method and need to set value of default day option to "all"

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#daysDropdown,#monthsDropdown,#yearsDropdown,#tzDropdown').on('change', function () {
        var day = $('#daysDropdown').val();
        var month = $('#monthsDropdown').val();
        var year = $('#yearsDropdown').val();
        var tz = $('#tzDropdown').val();
        SearchData(day, month, year, tz);
      });
    });

    function SearchData(day, month, year, tz) {
      if (day.toUpperCase() == 'ALL' && month.toUpperCase() == 'ALL' && year.toUpperCase() == 'ALL' && tz.toUpperCase() == 'ALL') {
        $('#data-table tbody tr').show();
      } else {
        $('#data-table tbody tr:has(td)').each(function () {
          var rowday = $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text());
          var rowmonth = $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text());
          var rowyear = $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(3)').text());
          var rowtz = $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(5)').text());

          if ((rowday == day || day == 'all') && (rowmonth.toUpperCase() == month.toUpperCase() || month == 'all') && (rowyear == year.toUpperCase() || year == 'all') && (rowtz.toUpperCase() == tz.toUpperCase() || tz == 'all')) {
            $(this).show();
          }
          else {
            $(this).hide();
          }
        }
        )
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<title>title</title>

<body class="maincontainer">
  <section class="container1">
    <div id="col-1">
      <br><br>
      <label>
        <h2>Filter By Month, Year and Time Zone:</h2>
      </label>
      <br><br>
      <div id="filter">
        <select id="daysDropdown" class="filter">
          <option value="all">Day</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
          <option value="13">13</option>
          <option value="14">14</option>
          <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="16">16</option>
          <option value="17">17</option>
          <option value="18">18</option>
          <option value="19">19</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="21">21</option>
          <option value="22">22</option>
          <option value="23">23</option>
          <option value="24">24</option>
          <option value="25">25</option>
          <option value="26">26</option>
          <option value="27">27</option>
          <option value="28">28</option>
          <option value="29">29</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="31">31</option>
        </select>
        <select id="monthsDropdown" class="filter">
          <option value="all">Month</option>
          <option value="Sep">September</option>
          <option value="Oct">October</option>
        </select>
        <select id="yearsDropdown" class="filter">
          <option value="all">Year</option>
          <option value="2021">2021</option>
          <option value="2022">2022</option>
        </select>
        <select id="tzDropdown" class="filter">
          <option value="all">Time Zone</option>
          <option value="Berlin - GMT+2">Berlin - GMT+2</option>
          <option value="Egypt - GMT+2">Egypt - GMT+2</option>
          <option value="Riyadh - GMT+2">Riyadh - GMT+2</option>
          <option value="Istanbul - GMT+3">Istanbul - GMT+3</option>
          <option value="Dubai - GMT+4">Dubai - GMT+4</option>
          <option value="Kuwait - GMT+4">Kuwait - GMT+4</option>
          <option value="Kuala Lumpur - GMT+8">Kuala Lumpur - GMT+8</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div id="col-2">
        <br><br>
        <div class="row">
          <div id="table-wrapper">
            <div id="table-scroll">
              <br><br>
              <table id="data-table" style="text-align: center; width: 828px;"
                class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered dataTable no-footer" role="grid"
                aria-describedby="data-table_info">

                <thead>
                  <tr role="row">
                    <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                      aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 197px;">
                      Name</th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                      aria-label="Date: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 49px;">Date</th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                      aria-label="Month: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 67px;">Month</th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                      aria-label="Year: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 45px;">Year</th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                      aria-label="Time: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 58px;">Time</th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                      aria-label="Time Zone: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 184px;">Time Zone</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 1</td>
                    <td>11</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>11:00:23</td>
                    <td>Riyadh - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 2</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>Sep</td>
                    <td>2021</td>
                    <td>18:45:42</td>
                    <td>Egypt - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 2</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>Sep</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>12:59:18</td>
                    <td>Egypt - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 2</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>Sep</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>16:20:37</td>
                    <td>Egypt - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 3</td>
                    <td>18</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>10:22:33</td>
                    <td>Kuala Lumpur - GMT+8</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 3</td>
                    <td>18</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>11:03:42</td>
                    <td>Kuala Lumpur - GMT+8</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 3</td>
                    <td>18</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>15:57:25</td>
                    <td>Kuala Lumpur - GMT+8</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 3</td>
                    <td>18</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>16:15:04</td>
                    <td>Kuala Lumpur - GMT+8</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 3</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>16:30:27</td>
                    <td>Kuala Lumpur - GMT+8</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 3</td>
                    <td>21</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>16:15:28</td>
                    <td>Kuala Lumpur - GMT+8</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 3</td>
                    <td>24</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>09:16:29</td>
                    <td>Kuala Lumpur - GMT+8</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 3</td>
                    <td>25</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>16:14:20</td>
                    <td>Kuala Lumpur - GMT+8</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 4</td>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td>Sep</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>09:15:55</td>
                    <td>Dubai - GMT+4</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 4</td>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td>Sep</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>12:10:23</td>
                    <td>Dubai - GMT+4</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 4</td>
                    <td>8</td>
                    <td>Sep</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>12:00:23</td>
                    <td>Dubai - GMT+4</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 4</td>
                    <td>11</td>
                    <td>Sep</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>11:25:02</td>
                    <td>Dubai - GMT+4</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 4</td>
                    <td>11</td>
                    <td>Sep</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>11:25:03</td>
                    <td>Dubai - GMT+4</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 4</td>
                    <td>14</td>
                    <td>Sep</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>09:23:27</td>
                    <td>Dubai - GMT+4</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 4</td>
                    <td>28</td>
                    <td>Sep</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>15:20:49</td>
                    <td>Dubai - GMT+4</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 4</td>
                    <td>9</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>10:02:22</td>
                    <td>Dubai - GMT+4</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>11</td>
                    <td>Sep</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>11:25:02</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>28</td>
                    <td>Sep</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>15:58:06</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>09:35:22</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>09:35:22</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>09:56:44</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>09:58:08</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>10:11:26</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>10:49:11</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>10:51:19</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>11:25:56</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>11:41:22</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>11:45:58</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>11:49:19</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>11:58:00</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>12:05:57</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>12:30:15</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>13:31:27</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>15:34:47</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>15:38:58</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>16:31:21</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>11</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>17:07:32</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>11</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>19:37:26</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>08:33:09</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>15:46:07</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>16:17:56</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>13</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>08:45:45</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>14</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>08:53:30</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>14</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>15:35:58</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>17</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>08:33:39</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>17</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>15:36:56</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>18</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>10:19:50</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>18</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>14:16:23</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>18</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>14:16:37</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>18</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>15:46:10</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>18</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>16:15:13</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>16:24:49</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>24</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>16:53:02</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>24</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>16:53:03</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Person 5</td>
                    <td>24</td>
                    <td>Oct</td>
                    <td>2022</td>
                    <td>16:53:09</td>
                    <td>Berlin - GMT+2</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            <br><br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </section>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Balkishan, that worked as expected, Thank you so much for your help , I appreciate it